# Android 4.0 Custom Dialog - possible Bug?

Tags: java, android

I am creating a custom Dialog with the following style:

```
<style name="FullHeightDialog" parent="android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

I put the following construction of the dialog:

```
public CustomDialog(Context context) {
    super(context, R.style.FullHeightDialog);
    setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_layout);
}
```

The custom_dialog_layout root is RelativeLayout with layout_margin="20dp", and inside I put LinearLayout with 3 simple Buttons.

I expect that the Dialog stretches to the full height and to the content width, in this case the LinearLayout with the 3 buttons.

It works fine on Android Gingerbread, BUT on Android 4, it never stretches more than ~40% of the screen.
On Android 4, I have to programatically set:

```
LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
params.width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
```

To make it work as expected. Even then, it shows non expected results, but nontheless, acceptable.

Is this a Bug of Ice Cream Sandwich or I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

your problem might come from `android:style/Theme.Dialog` since it can evolve depending on android version.

solutions :

1. Define fully your own style with no reference to `android:style/Theme.Dialog`
2. refers to `android:style/Theme.Dialog` but add margins/paddings layout definitions in your style items